# Como abrir uma nova pagina com codeigniter

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

Estou a tentando aprender um pouco sobre esse framework, toda hora encontro algo que não sei resolver, mas depois de muito esforço consigo resolver, e agora me deparei com esse probleminha e não achei nenhuma informação na internet para me guiar.

Eu sei que para chamar uma view eu utilizo este código abaixo

```
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('account/myview', $content_data, TRUE);
    $this->load->view($this->template, $data);
```

Mas eu não quero chamar uma view para ficar dentro do template, eu quero chamar uma view para preencher toda a pagina do site, sem nenhum conteúdo do template, mas com a mesma aparência e eu queria usar o controller para enviar um array com informações para esta nova pagina

Answer (score 0):

Consegui mudar de pagina apenas modificando isso, até que foi simples, e espero que esteja certo, funcionando está

```
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('account/myPage', $content_data, TRUE);
$this->load->view('account/myPage', $data);
```